# laravel validation is not working with predifined values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this code

```
{{Form::text('date_attribute_name', 'posting_date', array('placeholder' => 'Date Attribute Name', 'disabled'))}}
```

when I submit the code, I got error message that the `date_attribute_name` is required thought it is fill with `posting_date` text.

However, if i fill that input text myself, the validation works.

could you help please?

Answer (score 2):

This is your input:

```
Form::text('date_attribute_name', 'posting_date', array('placeholder' => 'Date Attribute Name', 'disabled'))
```

You have used `'disabled'` attribute in your `input` and disabled inputs are not submitted to the server when you submit the form. You need to remove the `disabled` attribute to make that `input` available in the server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I will try to do that using jquery when submitting the form and will update your. Anyway, I just posted another question, could you check please? man thanks +1

Comment: Welcome, I'm on it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is right. Maybe you have to fix the validation(or you could just use `'required'` into options array if you just need it to be required).

Comment: The validation is correct and the required syntax exists